# Can the screeenshots generated by selenium-shutterbug be saved with extension as jpg instead of png?

Tags: java, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-shutterbug

Selenium-shutterbug (https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug) saves screenshots as png, is there any way to save them as jpg?

For example:

```
Shutterbug.shootPage(driver,ScrollStrategy.WHOLE_PAGE_CHROME).withName(screenshotName).save(path);
```

Comment: ... ***Why?!?*** PNG is usually a better format in which to store a screen shot.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, you are not helping. I have my reasons.

Comment: @BMC it would be best to explain your reasons for having to use jpg to avoid people questioning why.

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code of [Snapshot.java](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug/blob/master/src/main/java/com/assertthat/selenium_shutterbug/core/Snapshot.java) for [selenium-shutterbug](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug) the variable **EXTENSION** is defined as:

```
private static final String EXTENSION = "PNG";
```

So using **selenium-shutterbug** you can't save the screenshot with extension as **`.JPG`**. It will be always saved in **`.PNG`** format.