# Difference between aShot and Shutterbug in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ashot, selenium-shutterbug

I a trying to learn capturing screenshots in selenium. Came to know about aShot() and Shutterbug classes which is a third party Api for webdriver.

What are the key Differences and Which has Advantages

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ashot

[ashot](https://github.com/pazone/ashot) is a [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) [screenshot](/questions/tagged/screenshot) utility to take screenshots, crop, prettify, compare. It can be used for the following purposes:

- Taking a screenshot of a WebElement on different platforms (i.e. desktop browsers, iOS Simulator Mobile Safari, Android Emulator Browser)
- Decorating screenshots.
- Providing flexible screenshot comparisons.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
    <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find a couple of detailed relevant discussions in:

- [How to capture screenshot of a WebElement within a webpage but not the entire screen or page through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015559/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-a-webelement-within-a-webpage-but-not-the-entire-sc/52054164#52054164)
- [How to take full page screenshot using AShot library through Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893208/how-to-take-full-page-screenshot-using-ashot-library-through-selenium-and-java/51893909#51893909)

---

### selenium-shutterbug

[selenium-shutterbug](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug) is a utility library written in Java for making screenshots using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) WebDriver and further customizing, comparing and processing them with the help of [Java AWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit).

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.assertthat</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-shutterbug</artifactId>
    <version>x.x</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Using Gradle:

```
compile ('com.assertthat:selenium-shutterbug:x.x') {
    exclude group: "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name: "selenium-java"
    }
```

Using SBT:

```
"com.assertthat" % "selenium-shutterbug" % "x.x" exclude("org.seleniumhq.selenium", "selenium-java"),
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Can the screeenshots generated by selenium-shutterbug be saved with extension as jpg instead of png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076479/can-the-screeenshots-generated-by-selenium-shutterbug-be-saved-with-extension-as/54092347#54092347)

---

### Difference

The big difference between them is, [ashot](/questions/tagged/ashot) works only when the webpage supports [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

---

### Reference

[How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: Hey regret for late upvote. I almost found all answer helpful, it was difficult to choose best one :)

Comment: I vote for aShot my example https://github.com/Ebazhanov/visual-regression-ashot-selenide

Answer (score 0):

**Ashot()** [source](http://www.qababu.com/2017/07/ashot-in-selenium-3-for-taking-full.html)

> Ashot() is a third party utility supported by Selenium WebDriver to
>   capture the screen shots. The below are the features supported by
>   aShot() utility with repect to screenshots:
>
> ```
> Capturing the entire page
> Capture the Web Element
> Prettifying the screenshot
> Screenshot comparison
> Several elements comparison
> ```
>
> Our focus here is on capturing the entire page and capturing the web
>   element screenshots.

**Shutterstock** [source](https://www.shutterstock.com/) Not sure whether its a tool to capture screenshots in selenium

> Shutterstock is an American provider of stock photography, stock
>   footage, stock music, and editing tools;

If you want to perform some other things like `Capturing the entire page`, `Screenshot comparison` etc. as mentioned above. Need some third part libraries. `aShot` is one of them.

Other then this we can simply capture only visible part screenshot using TakesScreenshot interface in Selenium.

Comment: The question was about Shutterbug [link](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug)  which is Utility library to create customized full page/frame/elements screenshots using Selenium WebDriver and Java AWT

Supported features: 
Capturing the entire pag,
Capturing the WebElement,
Capturing entire scrollable WebElement,
Capturing frame,
Screenshot comparison (with diff highlighting),
Creating thumbnails,
Highlighting element on the page,
Highlighting element on the page with added text,
Blur WebElement on the page (e.g. sensitive information),
Blur whole page,
and more...